# How many connected components can the intersection of a ball with an arbitrary domain have?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be an arbitrary domain (i.e. a connected and open subset). Let $x \in \Omega$ and $B_r(x)$ be the ball (w.r.t. euclidean metric) around $x$ with radius $r$.

How many connected components can the topological subspace $\Omega \cap B_r(x)$ have?

Take for example "the comb" ommitting the spike at $0$:

$$ C := ([0,1] \times \{0\}) \cup (K \times [0,2]) $$

with

$$ K := \left\{1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

By "thickening" the spikes and "smoothing" the corners I would get a domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Under this assumption taking

$$C \cap B_1\bigg((1/2,1)\bigg)$$

would give me countably many connected components. Is this example correct? Is there an example with uncountably many connected components?

Comment: Any open set in $\Bbb{R}^n$ has at most countably many connected components.

Comment: @Crostul: Ah, ok. So since the connected components of any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as well, there can't be more than countably many or else it would contradict second countability?

Comment: Yes: this is correct